# Azure DevOps PR Build Validation checks only one of the policies

Tags: azure, validation, azure-devops, pull-request

I have two build validations on the branch in which I am trying to merge a PR into. Only one of the policies is checked. Disabling the "build" policy would remove all build checks for the PR, so it's like the second one doesn't exist. The first policy and the second one are **identical** (except their names).

How can I make devops see the second validation?

My build validations for the branch targeted by the PR are as follows:

[image]

The checks for the PR are as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by abandoning the PR and then creating a new one. Seems like PRs keep a reference to all the build validations in place when the PR was made, and then track them using that. I thought I tried this and it didn't work the first time, I don't know what happened but it works now.

Still, I find it very counter-intuitive that you can enable/disable a build validation and it will have an effect on the PR, but you cannot add new ones.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)